# How to remove class from all list of an id with prototypejs

Tags: prototypejs

I want to remove all classes named **active** of all `<li>` under `<ul id="navNovelty">` using prototypejs.

I did `$('ul#navNovelty li').removeClassName('active');` but it did not work. Here is my full code

```
 <ul id="navNovelty" class="nav om">

<li id="multimedia" class="active"><a href="pages-afficher-index.php?nom_section=Multimedia" onClick="mettreajour('video', 'pages-afficher-index.php?nom_section=Multimedia', ''); return false"  class="nav-item">Multimedia</a></li>


<li id="love"><a href="pages-afficher-index.php?nom_section=Love" onClick="mettreajour('video', 'pages-afficher-index.php?nom_section=Love', '');   $('ul#navNovelty li').removeClassName('active');  $('love').addClassName('active'); return false" class="nav-item">Love & Family</a></li>

                                                                        <li><a href="pages-afficher-index.php?nom_section=MyBusiness" onClick="mettreajour('video', 'pages-afficher-index.php?nom_section=MyBusiness', ''); return false" class="nav-item">MyBusiness</a></li>
</ul>
```

**How to remove class from all list of an id with prototypejs ?**

Answer (score 0):

Unlike jQuery, Prototype has a different accessor for single elements and multiple elements. If you want to target a single item, and find it by its id, you use one dollar sign:

```
$('navNovelty').removeClassName('active');
```

If you want to access multiple items, you use two:

```
$$('ul#navNovelty li').map('removeClassName', 'active');
```